# bank account transaction report (table)

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to select a bank account transaction report from 3 tables: person, accounts and transaction. What I want for the result is a table with three columns:
Account Owner name | Transaction ID | The remainder of the account after the transaction. 
These are my raw tables :

```
--Person ===>>> 
CREATE TABLE "BANK"."ACCOUNTS" 
    "ID" NUMBER(*,0) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "PERSONID" NUMBER(*,0)

--Accounts ===>>>
 CREATE TABLE "BANK"."PERSON" 
    "ID" NUMBER(*,0) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "NAME" VARCHAR2

--Transactions ===>>>
CREATE TABLE "BANK"."TRANSACTION" 
    "ID" NUMBER(*,0) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "OAID" NUMBER,  -- Origin Account ID
    "DAID" NUMBER,  -- Destination Account ID
    "VALUE" FLOAT(126), 
    "TIMESTAMP" TIMESTAMP (6)
```

I've been struggling a lot with this and I haven't been able to think of the logic. I would Appreciate any help.

Comment: Give us some sample table data and the expected result - all as formatted text, not images- Also show us your current query attempt.

Comment: Your transaction table makes it look like all transactions are internal transactions from one account to another in the same bank. Is this so? And do you only want to show a user's transactions where their account is the origin account or do you want to include transactions where their account is the destination account?

Comment: On a sidenote: Never use `FLOAT`. This is an approximate datatype. Use the precise type `NUMBER` instead.

Comment: @jarlh as I said before I have NO current query attempt I can't think of any logic that would give me the result I want, and I described The Result perfectly clear:  I want a list of all transactions for one account, haven't you ever downloaded your VISA report? a list of transactions for one account what matters in that is the remain on the account after each transaction.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner YEAH tnx I didn't pay attention to that.

Comment: "The Result perfectly clear". Well, but the source isn't. You have failed to show some sample data. So, a transaction seems to be a transfer from one account to another. It seems all transfers occur inside the same bank. A transaction may be transfer of 10$ from account A to account B. So two accounts are involved, one getting 10$, one losing them. Or does a mirror transaction with swapped accounts exist, where the value is -10$? This is important to know in order to write the query.

Comment: And then, do you want transactions in your results that don't change a person's balance? if both accounts in a transaction belong to the same user, then that transaction doesn't change the user's balance. Show the transaction or not? You see, what seems very obvious for you, isn't so obvious after all.

Comment: And what you are looking for is an algorithm? So that you can write a query based on it? It's not really clear where exactly you are stuck.

Answer (score 0):

here is a query that may help you:

```
select p.name as account_owner, t.id as transaction_id, 
SUM(case when t.oaid = a.id then -t.value else t.value end) 
OVER(PARTITION BY a.id ORDER BY t.timestamp RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS remainder 
from bank.person p
inner join bank.accounts a on a.personid = p.id
inner join bank.transaction t on t.oaid = a.id or t.daid = a.id
```

for any clarifications dont hesitate to comment.

Comment: thank you very much, could you explain the RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW" part to me

Comment: I don't quite understand this: An analytic function that uses the RANGE keyword can use multiple sort keys in its ORDER BY clause if it specifies any of the following windows:

RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW. The short form of this is RANGE UNBOUNDED PRECEDING.

Comment: Here is an explanation http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_advanced_sql_windowing_clause.htm